# How to access the user-defined style sheet in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, stylesheet

After loading an HTML page, I can access all style sheets by `document.styleSheets` collection. But this collection is not including user-defined style sheet.

Therefore, if user has specified a user-defined style sheet in IE, I cannot know whether an element is controlled by user.

I am using the C++ interface `IHTMLDocument2` on the client side. Is there any way to know if a user-defined style sheet is activated?

Answer (score 0):

User defined stylesheets are not accessible in IE.

I read this in the documentation here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533039(v=vs.85).aspx. Even though the content is archived I believe it is factually correct until any new documentation declares otherwise.

> User-defined style sheets are not included in the [styleSheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531200(v=vs.85).aspx) collection